# What is the regex to match this pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the following text. The pattern is an item starting with a number such as 2.1 on a new line, followed by one or more such items. Some items can spread over multiple lines like 2.1. I want to match a block of such items.

The pattern would be:

(A new line starting with numbers such as 2.1, possibly followed by one or more lines not starting numbers such as 2.1) followed by one or more such patterns

```
2.1 [ii] Agreement and Plan of Reorganization, by and among the Company,
Force Acq. Corp. and Force Computers, Inc. as amended.
3.1 [viii] Articles of Incorporation of Company, as amended.
3.2 [viii] Bylaws of Company.
10.1 [I] Preferred Stock Purchase Agreement dated September 29, 1983,
together with amendments thereto dated February 28, 1984 and
10.2 [I] Form of Indemnification Agreement between Company and its
officers, directors and certain other key employees.
10.3 [I] Amendment to form of Indemnification Agreement.
10.4 [iv] 1983 Incentive Stock Option Plan, as amended August 13, 1991.
10.5 [vi] 1988 Employee Stock Purchase Plan, as amended October 1992.
10.6 [v] Amended and Restated 1992 Stock Option Plan.
```

Here is my regex:

```
pattern = r"(?:\n\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}.{1,200}){2,}\n"

text = re.sub(pattern,"", text, re.S)
```

Not quite there yet. Dotall doesn't help. Thank you!

As an intermediate step, how to match a line not starting with \d{1,2}.\d{1,2}? Negative lookbehind does not work for variable length.

Here are some more sample texts:

```
2.01 Acquisition Agreement dated as of March 26, 1997 by and between
registrant and ISAR-Vermogensverwaltung Gbr mbH ("ISAR")(1)

3.01 Registrant's Amended and Restated Articles of Incorporation, as
amended(2)

3.02 Registrant's Certificate of Amendment of Articles of
Incorporation filed prior to the closing of registrant's initial
public offering(2)

3.03 Registrant's Amended and Restated Articles of Incorporation
filed following the closing of registrant's initial public
offering(2)

3.04 Registrant's Bylaws(2)
3.05 Registrant's Amended and Restated Bylaws adopted prior to the
closing of registrant's initial public offering(2)
3.06 Certificate of Amendment of Amended and Restated Articles of
Versant Object Technology Corporation(7)

3.07 Registrant's Certificate of Determination dated July 12, 1999,
incorporated by reference to the Company's current report on
Form 8-K (Exhibit 3.01) filed July 12, 1999.

4.01 [intentionally omitted]
4.02 Preferred Stock Purchase Agreement, dated as of April 27, 1994,
as amended(2)

10.01 Registrant's 1989 Stock Option Plan, as amended, and related
documents(2)**

10.02 Registrant's 1996 Equity Incentive Plan, as amended, and related
documents(3)**

10.03 Registrant's 1996 Directors Stock Option Plan, as amended, and
related documents(4)**
```

The distinctive features are: 
(1) They start with numbers such as 2.01 and 10.03
(2) There are many of them (at least 2) clustering together. 
The irregularities are: 
(1) Some spread over multiple lines such as 2.01, and some are on one line such as 2.04. 
(2) There may or may not be blank lines between them, as between 2.01 and 3.01, and no between 3.04 and 3.05.

I want to match this full block of such text and remove it. Other texts are regular sentences. A few of them may start with numbers such as 2.1 for headings, but they don't cluster together, as the above text.

Comment: Your trying to match the entire text or the individual lines?

Comment: What specifically about it do you want to match?  `.*` would also match this text.

Comment: I want to match the entire text. These are a list of exhibits. I want to remove them before I analyze the rest of the text, since they have no information content.

Comment: Also I want to avoid negative positives, so I add {2,}. If there are at least two consecutive blocks of text starting with numbers like 2.1 on a new line, then I will remove them.

Comment: As @paddy has said, `.*` is the perfect pattern that would match this "text". You see, `1` is a digit but if I said "I want to match `1`, what pattern do I use?", the answer is `1`, not `\d`. You need to describe what elements your regex _should_ and _should not_ match and then possibly provide an example (text) that fits that description.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture each component, you can group them for each. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/DYGIqW/1).

```
import re

mylist = ['2.1 [ii] Agreement and Plan of Reorganization, by and among the Company, Force Acq. Corp. and Force Computers, Inc. as amended.',
          '3.1 [viii] Articles of Incorporation of Company, as amended.',
          '3.2 [viii] Bylaws of Company.',
          '10.1 [I] Preferred Stock Purchase Agreement dated September 29, 1983, together with amendments thereto dated February 28, 1984 and',
          '10.2 [I] Form of Indemnification Agreement between Company and its officers, directors and certain other key employees.'
         ]
for item in mylist:
    regex = re.search('(?P<chapter>\d+[.]\d+)\s+(?P<subchapter>\[.*\])\s+(?P<title>.*)', item)
    regex = regex.groups()
    print (regex[0], regex[1], regex[2])
```

Output:

```
2.1 [ii] Agreement and Plan of Reorganization, by and among the Company, Force Acq. Corp. and Force Computers, Inc. as amended.
3.1 [viii] Articles of Incorporation of Company, as amended.
3.2 [viii] Bylaws of Company.
10.1 [I] Preferred Stock Purchase Agreement dated September 29, 1983, together with amendments thereto dated February 28, 1984 and
10.2 [I] Form of Indemnification Agreement between Company and its officers, directors and certain other key employees.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have each paragraph as an item, I suggest the following:

```
import re
text = """ 2.1 [ii] Agreement and Plan of Reorganization, by and among the Company,
Force Acq. Corp. and Force Computers, Inc. as amended.
3.1 [viii] Articles of Incorporation of Company, as amended.
3.2 [viii] Bylaws of Company.
10.1 [I] Preferred Stock Purchase Agreement dated September 29, 1983,
together with amendments thereto dated February 28, 1984 and
10.2 [I] Form of Indemnification Agreement between Company and its
officers, directors and certain other key employees.
10.3 [I] Amendment to form of Indemnification Agreement.
10.4 [iv] 1983 Incentive Stock Option Plan, as amended August 13, 1991.
10.5 [vi] 1988 Employee Stock Purchase Plan, as amended October 1992.
10.6 [v] Amended and Restated 1992 Stock Option Plan."""

text = re.findall(r"\d{1,2}\.\d+.*?(?=\d{1,2}\.\d+|$)", text, re.S)

for paragraph in text:
    print(paragraph)
```

This yields:

```
2.1 [ii] Agreement and Plan of Reorganization, by and among the Company,
Force Acq. Corp. and Force Computers, Inc. as amended.

3.1 [viii] Articles of Incorporation of Company, as amended.

3.2 [viii] Bylaws of Company.

10.1 [I] Preferred Stock Purchase Agreement dated September 29, 1983,
together with amendments thereto dated February 28, 1984 and

10.2 [I] Form of Indemnification Agreement between Company and its
officers, directors and certain other key employees.

10.3 [I] Amendment to form of Indemnification Agreement.

10.4 [iv] 1983 Incentive Stock Option Plan, as amended August 13, 1991.

10.5 [vi] 1988 Employee Stock Purchase Plan, as amended October 1992.

10.6 [v] Amended and Restated 1992 Stock Option Plan.
```

The key is the **?** behind **.***, so that the evaluation is lazy. This means that the regular expression matches everything it has to but not more. If you leave the **?** it matches the rest of the string.

**(?=...)** lets you omit the regular expression in your result, so that you just match everything until the next paragraph. I hope this helps.